# caching/indexing queries after I am certain none of the results will ever change

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

So, as the title suggests, I am working on a solution that offers editing options for my data to some degree, but after I close a case, the data in the case will NEVER change.

My question is, is there a way for me to index the whole query that generates the report for closed cases, since the results never change, and benefit performance wise?

Views maybe?

Comment: Views typically are simply *stored* SQL queries - they don't actually have their data, if you select from a view, you basically select from the referenced base tables. As such, views are typically a poor choice for performance tuning

Comment: You could probably use an indexed view, or a filtered index. Pretty difficult to be less generic without knowing how much data you have, what your table structure is, what queries you need to optimise etc.

Comment: If the data will never change you could insert the results of the query into a separate table. A view (unless it's an indexed view) will not be materialized but is rather a stored query that will get executed whenever there's a SELECT against that view.

Comment: Are you having a performance problem right now, or are you just trying to optimize?

Comment: I am trying to optimize so I can offer more data allowance to the end-user at no additional cost . The queries are as optimized as possible.

Comment: I personally would not do what you're trying to do. There's a certain complexity involved in treating closed cases in a different way than open cases. Until you're talking about millions or billions of cases, I would not treat closed cases any differently than open cases, regardless of whether the data will change or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a materialized view.  In SQL Server it is called [an indexed view.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)  Creating the clustered index will have the net effect of storing the query results.